# Modifying Dijkstra's algorithm for least changes

Tags: python, algorithm, python-2.7, graph-algorithm, dijkstra

I'm using a version of Dijkstra's algorithm written in Python which I found online, and it works great. But because this is for bus routes, changing 10 times might be the shortest route, but probably not the quickest and definitely not the easiest. I need to modify it somehow to return the path with the least number of changes, regardless of distance to be honest (obviously if 2 paths have equal number of changes, choose the shortest one). My current code is as follows:

```
from priodict import priorityDictionary

def Dijkstra(stops,start,end=None):
    D = {}  # dictionary of final distances
    P = {}  # dictionary of predecessors
    Q = priorityDictionary()   # est.dist. of non-final vert.
    Q[start] = 0

    for v in Q:
        D[v] = Q[v]
        print v
        if v == end: break

        for w in stops[v]:
            vwLength = D[v] + stops[v][w]
            if w in D:
                if vwLength < D[w]:
                    raise ValueError, "Dijkstra: found better path to already-final vertex"
            elif w not in Q or vwLength < Q[w]:
                Q[w] = vwLength
                P[w] = v
    return (D,P)

def shortestPath(stops,start,end):
    D,P = Dijkstra(stops,start,end)
    Path = []
    while 1:
        Path.append(end)
        if end == start: break
        end = P[end]
    Path.reverse()
    return Path

stops = MASSIVE DICTIONARY WITH VALUES (7800 lines)
print shortestPath(stops,'Airport-2001','Comrie-106')
```

I must be honest - I aint no mathematician so I don't quite understand the algorithm fully, despite all my research on it.

I have tried changing a few things but I don't get even close.

Any help? Thanks!

Comment: If you only care about the least amount of bus changes, without regarding distance, wouldn't http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Breadth-first_search be more suitable for you?

Comment: I'v spent the last 3 days getting Dijkstra's algorithm up and running and preparing a dictionary for it. I was hopping someone could help me mod it slightly - saving me from having to start it all over..
My current thinking is to add a multiplier to each edge, almost adding a "penalty" for extra routes taken. Shall see how this works out..
But thanks for the reply :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a possible solution:

1)Run breadth first search from the start vertex. It will find the path with the least number of changes, but not the shortest among them. Let's assume that after running breadth first search dist[i] is the distance between the start and the i vertex.

2)Now one can run Djikstra algorithm on modified graph(add only those edges from the initial graph which satisfy this condition: dist[from] + 1 == dist[to]). The shortest path in this graph is the one you are looking for.

P.S If you don't want to use breadth first search, you can use Djikstra algorithm after making all edges' weights equal to 1.

Comment: Changing all the edges weights to 1 - wouldn't that almost leave it to luck to not take extra routes? If it happens to go through a node that leads eventually to the end, although it isn't necessary, the script wouldn't know to omit it?
Using your idea of changing the weights however has worked. I added a multiplier of 2 to all weights. It now chooses the path with least nodes as it now has a substantially shorter distance :D

Comment: Changing the weights to 1 is necessary to emulate breadth first search with Djikstra algorithm. There is no luck involved here: it finds the shortest path in terms of number of changes during the first step, and the shortest in terms of distance among them during the second step.

Comment: Ooooh ok I see. Perfect. Iv done that and it's going :) Thank you so much

Answer (score 0):

What i would do is to add an offset to the actual costs if you have to change the line. For example if your edge weights represent the time needed between 2 stations, i would add the average waiting time between Line1 Line2 at station X (e.g. 0.5*maxWaitingTime) during the search process. Of course this is a heuristic solution for the problem. If your timetables are known, you can calculate a "exact" solution or at least a solution that satisfies the model because in reality you can't assume that every bus is always on time.

Answer (score 0):

The solution is simple: instead of using the distances as weights, use a wright of 1 for each stop. Dijkstra's algorithm will minimize the number of changes as you requested (the total path weight is the number of rides, which is the number of changes +1). If you want to use the distance to break ties, use something like

```
 vwLength = D[v] + 1+ alpha*stops[v][w]
```

where alpha<<1, e.g. alpha=0.0001

Practically, I think you're approach is exaggerated. You don't want to fly from Boston to Toronto through Paris even if two of flights are the minimum. I would play with alpha to get an approximation of total traveling time, which is what probably matters.